# Call JsonResult via Ajax in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new in Ajax! I have a delete jsonResult with this definition :

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Delete(ContactViewModel contactUsViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _contactUsService.Remove(contactUsViewModel.Id);
            }
            return Json("");
        }
```

I wanna to call this action in a popUp modal via ajax call , what I have write to this is like this:

```
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Contact", new { contactId = Model.Id }, null)
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#test").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Contact")'
            });

        });
    })
</script>
```

how can I call this jsonresult ?

Comment: you are already calling it. what you're not doing is sending or capturing a json result.

Comment: I know I go through the right way , but page not found exception shown!

Comment: How can I call delete operation without having any get jsonresult ? I wanna to call post jsonresult

Comment: @DaveA There is no link with id `test`, he didn't send model and he need to prevent default link navigation (GET request). Why you think, that he calling action?

Comment: @webdeveloper, if that's the case I'm lost. I only see contactId being sent. That's what I think. Why a Delete needs a model I'm lost about. Please clarify why an ID isnt enough for a DELETE

Comment: @DaveA `id` is enough, but he wrote `ContactViewModel contactUsViewModel`.

Comment: @webdeveloper, interesting this matters to you more than an optimal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to write only `id` in your action, no need for all properties.

Try this:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult Delete(int contactId)
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         _contactUsService.Remove(contactId);
     }
     return Json("");
 }
```

Html:

```
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Contact", new { contactId = Model.Id }, new { @class = "delete" })
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".delete").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var link = this.href;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'Post',
                url: link,
                success: function (data) { }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: @EricNielsen `Contact` is your controller? Any javascript errors?

Comment: I don't know what's the problem with that, I don't either have any javascript error